# Tooltip from bootstrap not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have looked everywhere, even here! I have tried every code but I still can't get the tooltips to work in BootStrap! I'm getting really frustrated!!

Does anyone have the js code that actually works? I would be really thankfulif you shared it.

I'm using BootStrap 3.0

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you declared jquery and bootstrap.js in your page ?

Comment: Yupp. I made sure everything was correct. I even placed them in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copypasted from working project:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.tooltip_cell').tooltip({container: 'body'})
});

<td class="tooltip_cell" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip text"> Some text</td>
```